# iOS-PERL translate perl regex to nsregularexpression

Tags: php, ios

In my app i want to do some sanity check for a username before i send it to a server for registration. I know that the following regular expressions will be used on the server, so i would like to check the username against the same expression in my app. However i'm bad at regexes. 
Could someone please help me out and translate these 2 expressions for me, so i can give them as a parameter for an `NSRegularExpression` please?

```
if (preg_match('/[^\x{80}-\x{F7} a-z0-9@_.\'-]/i', $name)) {
    return t('The username contains an illegal character.');
  }
  if (preg_match('/[\x{80}-\x{A0}' . // Non-printable ISO-8859-1 + NBSP
  '\x{AD}' . // Soft-hyphen
  '\x{2000}-\x{200F}' . // Various space characters
  '\x{2028}-\x{202F}' . // Bidirectional text overrides
  '\x{205F}-\x{206F}' . // Various text hinting characters
  '\x{FEFF}' . // Byte order mark
  '\x{FF01}-\x{FF60}' . // Full-width latin
  '\x{FFF9}-\x{FFFD}' . // Replacement characters
  '\x{0}-\x{1F}]/u', // NULL byte and control characters
  $name)) {
    return t('The username contains an illegal character.');
  }
```

Sincerely,

Zoli

Comment: preg_match is not perl...

Comment: What an awful sanity check. Much safer to white list "good"chars than black list "bad" chars. Your list is full of holes (e.g. U+FFFF)

Comment: that's the thing. i don't understand these regular expressions. However that's the same code the server checks the username against.